# Combining AngularJS with another SPA framework - compiling injected HTML

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I have an old single page app and for some new pages within the app I would like to use Angular, without changing how navigation and the app in general works already.

I would like to instantiate the angular app just once since it is running within a SPA already. I can do that either using `ng-app` attribute or programmatically using `angular.bootstrap` method. 
But then when user navigates to a new page and the old app loads the HTML and inject it to DOM, I want the new page to be processes by Angular. I understand the new HTML must be compiled by Angular. Is there an efficient way to do it? The HTML is already in DOM, I don't want to remove it, compile it and inject it again. Is there an efficient way of doing it?

The new page's HTML can look like this for example:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
     <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
```

The controller is created in app.js and loaded in index.html. It' simple for the test and looks like that:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'some title';
    }]);
```

Alternatively for each page I can instantiate the app using already mentioned `angular.bootstrap`, which does the trick, but that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is:

1) in the main (app) module getting reference to `$compile` and `$rootScope` in `app.run` and storing the reference outside Angular

2) in the old app navigation, after navigation to a new page happens calling:

```
$compile(pageRoot.contents())($rootScope);
```